# Can you make if/then scripts in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, script

Is it possible to combine multiple scripts into one in ffmpeg?

What I am trying to do is create one master script that changes commands based on the aspect ratio of the input video.

For example, if the input video is closest to a 16:9 aspect ratio, ffmpeg will automatically convert the video using script "A".

If the input video is closest to a 4:3 aspect ratio, ffmpeg will automatically convert the video using script "B".

Finally, if the input video has a strange aspect ratio, (for example, cell phone videos) ffmpeg will automatically convert the video using script "C".

I am new to ffmpeg and do not understand much. If possible, will you please give a script that I can simply copy and paste into ffmpeg?

I already have scripts A, B, and C ready.

Also, as a side question, can you command ffmpeg to delete the original input video after successfully converting it?

Thanks everyone